# How to write to next row on destination worksheet when looping through multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in excel, activated by a button, to copy rows of data from mostly blank worksheets, and need each row to stack beneath the next on the destination worksheet.  Data will be added to these worksheets as more information comes in, and will need to be updated on a regular basis.  However, I can't seem to get more than two rows copied.

I have tried row = row + 1 in what seems like would be the appropriate areas.  I also have tried some "last row" solutions found on the internet, without success.  I think the wrinkle is the For loop through i and j in each sheet, but I could just be making a really simple mistake in using others solutions.

```
Sub Update_Model()

    Dim trackerWks As Worksheet
    Dim dataWks As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rgdataWks As Range
    Dim row As Long

    Set dataWks = Worksheets("PMD COLLECTION")
    Set rgdataWks = dataWks.Range("A3:VD1500")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case UCase(ws.Name)
    Case "FLEET STATUS", "CRACK THRESHOLDS", "PMD COLLECTION", "CALCULATIONS"
    ' do nothing
    Case Else

    row = row + 1
    Set trackerWks = Worksheets(ws.Name)
    Set rg = ws.Range("A5:VF150")

    For i = 1 To 150
        If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(row, 1)) Then
            For j = 1 To 72
                If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 1))) Then
                rgdataWks.Cells(row, (j * 4)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, ((j * 4)  + 1)).Value2
                rgdataWks.Cells(row, ((j * 4) + 1)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, 1).Value2
                rgdataWks.Cells(row, ((j * 4) + 1)).NumberFormat = "dd mmm yy"
                rgdataWks.Cells(row, ((j * 4) + 2)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, 3).Value2
                rgdataWks.Cells(row, ((j * 4) + 3)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 3)).Value2
                End If
            Next j
        rgdataWks.Cells(row, 1).Value2 = 1
        End If
    row = row + 1
    Next i

    End Select

    Next




End Sub
```

I would expect this to write to a new row after every j and in between every worksheet.  Instead, it writes the first two lines of the first worksheet, and nothing more.
I know the worksheet loop works, because if I remove the "row = row + 1" statements, only one line appears, which is the last line of the last worksheet.

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------

After using tinman's suggestion to iterate the row inside the If statement, I got all of the first worksheet onto the destination page.  However, the next worksheet doesn't copy over.  Does anyone have advice on how to get the next worksheet moving?

Here is my Minimum Reproducible Example... I think.  I'm new, so if you need more or less, let me know.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Select Case UCase(ws.Name)
            Case "..."
            Case Else
                Set trackerWks = Worksheets(ws.Name)
                Set rg = ws.Range("A5:VF150")
                    For i = 1 To 150
                        row = row + 1
                        If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(row, 1)) Then
                            For j = 1 To 72
                                If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 1))) Then
                                    ...
                                    ...
                                End If
                            Next j
                        End If
                    Next i  
        End Select
    Next ws   
End Sub
```

Comment: Bit hard to tell - we could do with an [mcve]. As an aside, you do realise that `rg.Cells(row, 1)` is A5 when row=1?

Comment: Hm that does mean that whenever you run this code you will overwrite as you are starting the results at A5.

Comment: `row` should be incremented inside the if statement.

Comment: SJR, yes I realize that is A5, that column is for the date of inspection, and each row is a different date.  Each worksheet is a different vehicle, but the columns are all the same.

Comment: And SJR, yes, I want to overwrite the destination sheet every time it is run, as it is the collection point.  Each inspection is added on an individual vehicle, and I am collecting the mass data on the destination sheet.  If it didn't overwrite, I would get duplicates of previous inspections on the destination sheet when a new inspection was added.

Comment: OK so they're not the issues. After one loop, `row` could be as much as 150 so when you come to the next sheet `rg.Cells(row, 1)` will be outside "A5:VF150". Think you need to look at something like Cyril's approach.

Comment: @ SJR, I used TinMan's suggestion to get the first sheet iterating rows properly.  Now the next sheet doesn't copy over.  I edited my original post to include the new code.  Help please?

Comment: @TinMan, I used your suggestion, fixed part of the problem.  Please see my edit above and see if you can help with the next step.

Comment: @Mike1911 you should break up your code into smaller easier to test subs and functions.  What is the significance of `A5:VF150`?  Should this be a dynamic range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to determine last row on the destinatino sheet each time you paste, similar to:

```
Dim dest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, lrd As Long
Set dest = Worksheets("Dest")
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Dest" Then
        ws.UsedRange.Copy
        lrd = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'LAST ROW DEST
        dest.Cells(lrd + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    End If
Next ws
```

---

**Edit1:**

Used the above as a quick example to indicate that you want to find the lrd (last row destination) before you assign a destination.  Here is something using your code:

```
For i = 1 To 150 'CYRIL COMMENT:  True Case row loop
    If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(row, 1)) Then
        lrd = rgdataWks.Cells(rgdataWks.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'ADDED, may need to change col A reference
        For j = 1 To 72 'CYRIL COMMENT:  True Case column loop
            If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 1))) Then
                rgdataWks.Cells(lrd+1, (j * 4)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, ((j * 4)  + 1)).Value2
                rgdataWks.Cells(lrd+1, ((j * 4) + 1)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, 1).Value2
                rgdataWks.Cells(lrd+1, ((j * 4) + 1)).NumberFormat = "dd mmm yy"
                rgdataWks.Cells(lrd+1, ((j * 4) + 2)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, 3).Value2
                rgdataWks.Cells(lrd+1, ((j * 4) + 3)).Value2 = rg.Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 3)).Value2
            End If
        Next j
        rgdataWks.Cells(lrd+1, 1).Value2 = 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I see how that would work if I was trying to copy the entire 150 row range from each worksheet, but right now there are only a couple rows on each worksheet.  Also, the destination sheet requires ordered pairs for the next step in my project.  I am using the two For statements with i and j to filter for occupied rows and columns, and copy specific information over.  How can I put the For and If Not statements into your example?

Comment: @Mike1911 I used the `.UsedRange.Copy` as a general example, though you can do all of your efforts by replacing the `If`-statement I provided (since you use a Select Case to determine the appropriate sheet names).  When your `If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(row, 1)) Then` is met, then determine the `lrd` and use `lrd+1` in your `.value=.value` statements.  Will make a quick edit to my answer to give a better idea about what I mean.

Comment: well, that did....something. I do have all data now... but each row has two completely blank rows between them, and every third row has a 1 in column A (I intended to leave a 1 in column A for each occupied row to use the lrd) down to row 1502, with the second sheet's data on rows 455 and 458.

Comment: @Mike1911 2 blanks per, and you're not using a step function or anything... my only guess is `If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(row, 1)) Then` is throwing a True and causing values to start.  What is how those rows are completely blank, even no "1" in column A...

Comment: I replaced the row in  ```If Not IsEmpty(rg.Cells(row, 1)) Then``` with i, this stopped excel from copying the column A 1s through the entire 1500 row range, all of the data follows one after the other.  I still have two blank rows between each row... but I think I can live with that.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should break you code up into smaller units.  The fewer tasks that a subroutine performs the easier it is to read, modify, and debug.

Notice that the my code allows you to test adding a row to PMD COLLECTION without having to iterate of the data in multiple worksheets:

> ```
> AppendPMDRow "testing", 1, 2, 3
> ```

You can also test that a single worksheet without having to iterate over all the worksheets:

> ```
>   ProcessTrackerWorksheet Worksheets("TestData")
> ```

### Sample Code

```
Sub Update_Model()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Select Case UCase(ws.Name)
            Case "FLEET STATUS", "CRACK THRESHOLDS", "PMD COLLECTION", "CALCULATIONS"

            Case Else
                ProcessTrackerWorksheet ws
        End Select
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub ProcessTrackerWorksheet(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    With ws
        For r = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            If Len(.Cells(r, 1).Value) > 0 Then
                For c = 2 To 72 * 4 Step 4
                    AppendPMDRow .Cells(r, c).Value, .Cells(r, 1).Value, .Cells(r, 3).Value, .Cells(r, c + 2).Value
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub AppendPMDRow(ParamArray Values() As Variant)
    Dim target As Range
    With Worksheets("PMD COLLECTION")
       Set target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       target.Resize(1, UBound(Values)).Value = Values
    End With
End Sub
```